# Set the caret position always to end in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, caret

In my project, I am trying to set the caret position always to the end of the text. I know this is default behaviour but when we add some text dynamically, then the caret position changes to starting point in Chrome and firefox (IE is fine, amazing).

Anyway to make it to work properly in chrome and firefox?

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxQdV/)**

```
<div id="result" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button class="click">click to add text</butto>
```

---

```
var result = $('#result');
$('.click').click(function () {
    var preHtml = result.html();
    result.html(preHtml + "hello");
    result.focus();
});
```

I tried adding `setStart` and `setEnd` as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2635853/1577396) but no use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871081/jquery-setting-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div please check this .

Comment: @rahularyansharma Thanks.. this is not working though. (maybe I am doing something wrong as I am poor in JS).

Comment: I am also checking the same. Give me some time please .

Comment: hmmm really not working!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/1577396) thanks to Tim down :). The problem was that I was calling

```
placeCaretAtEnd($('#result'));
```

Instead of

```
placeCaretAtEnd(($('#result').get(0));
```

as mentioned by  jwarzech in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser/4238971#comment10900078_4238971).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hxQdV/1/)

Comment: Too good. Was looking for this for  quite a while. Glad to find a working solution.

Comment: same here, it works, thanks!

Comment: this fiddle isn't working if you add another nested span with text, the focus of the caret will go into the nested span.