# Implementing Hashtags using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want to do is basically is that whenever I write anything that starts with a #, the color of the tagged string should change to some other color, say blue, immediately. And when I press space to end the string, the color should change back to black. I tried a logic like this on a contenteditable div:

```
    if (# is pressed) 
    hashtagging = true
    append "<span>" to div

    if (space is pressed and hashtagging is true) 
    hashtagging = false
    append "</span>" to div
```

This is not working as expected.

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: Psuedo-code doesn't tend to work very well when used literally ;) post your actual code please

Comment: It's more or less like the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
$(function() {

    var hashtags = false;

    $(document).on('keydown', '#myInputField', function (e) {        
        arrow = {
            hashtag: 51,
            space: 32
        };

        var input_field = $(this);
        switch (e.which) {
            case arrow.hashtag:
                input_field.val(input_field.val() + "<span class='highlight'>");
                hashtags = true;
                break;
            case arrow.space:
                if(hashtags) {
                    input_field.val(input_field.val() + "</span>");
                    hashtags = false;
                }
                break;
        }

    });

});
```

Now this code checks on keydown if the hashtag or space is pressed and adds a span with a class for styling to it. Reason for checking for keydown instead of keyup is to add the tags before the actual input is added to the textfield. I used a text-field as input, but modify it with whatever you need.

Comment: This doesn't work that well. Because html tags can't be appended to a textarea or an input field. We have to use a div with contenteditable="true". But for that the .val() method doesn't work. If .html() is used instead the caret jumps to the start of the input. Though it's pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Both .text() and .html() have this strange tendency to send the caret to the beginning in a contenteditable div.

Comment: @shival Yeah ok, I assumed you were using a textfield or textarea and outputting it somewhere else, but I see now you mentioned you've done it on a contenteditable. Sorry about not reading the question properly. Haven't really used that too much so not 100% sure how this would translate to a contenteditable in the best way, but hopefully you can at least use some of this code to make it work.

Comment: contenteditable was a pain to work with, but just for fun I created a solution that uses a hidden textarea and displays the output to a div instead. I know it's not what you were looking for, but if it's any good here's a fiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/UfCTm/

Comment: Yes, on top of that I can't understand why does the caret position has to change after we use .text() or .html(). I used a javascript function that sets the caret position to the end and hybridized your solution with that function. It works well now, though is still a little buggy. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example, done by incorporating the solution given by Sondre with the solution by Mr_Green ([Set the caret position always to end in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230720/set-the-caret-position-always-to-end-in-contenteditable-div)) to place the caret at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/344m4/1/

```
var hashTagList = [];

function logHashList(){
    hashTagList = [];
    $('.highlight').each(function(){
        hashTagList.push(this.innerHTML);
    });
    for(var i=0;i&lt;hashTagList.length;i++){
        alert(hashTagList[i]);
    }
    if(hashTagList.length==0){
        alert('You have not typed any hashtags');
    }
}
$(function() {

    var hashtags = false;

    $(document).on('keydown', '#example-one', function (e) {        
        arrow = {
            hashtag: 51,
            space: 32
        };

        var input_field = $(this);
        switch (e.which) {
            case arrow.hashtag:
                e.preventDefault();
                input_field.html(input_field.html() + "<span class='highlight'>#");
                placeCaretAtEnd(this);
                hashtags = true;
                break;
            case arrow.space:       
                if(hashtags) {         
                    e.preventDefault();
                    input_field.html(input_field.html() + "</span>&nbsp;");    
                    placeCaretAtEnd(this);
                    hashtags = false;
                }
                break;
        }

    });

});


function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```