# Creating hashtags in contenteditable with keypress

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

**Edit: code below only works in Chrome/Opera**

I've modified the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154736/implementing-hashtags-using-jquery/#20637358) to create hashtags in a contenteditable using the keypress event. Basically, whenever someone types the hash (#) symbol, a span tag (styled via Bootstrap and other css) is immediately created and closes whenever a space or any punctuation character is pressed. That's the long and short of it.

Here's my code:

```js
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}

// closes the span housing the hashtag
function closeSpan(){
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("data-role", "remove");
  span.setAttribute("class", "delHashtag");
  span.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
 return span;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 var hashtags = false;
  
  $(document).on('keypress', '#myInputField', function(e) {
    var input_field = $(this);
    var x = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (x == 32){ // space key
      if(hashtags){
        e.preventDefault();
        input_field.html(input_field.html() + "</span>&nbsp;");
        placeCaretAtEnd(this);
        hashtags = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("new")[0].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
     document.getElementsByClassName("new")[0].appendChild(closeSpan());
      }
    }
    if (x == 35){ // hash key (#)
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".tag").removeClass("new");
      input_field.html(input_field.html() + "<span class='tag label label-info new'>#");
      placeCaretAtEnd(this);
      hashtags = true;
    }
    // various punctuation characters
    if (x == 8 || x == 9 || x >=16 && x <= 18 || x == 27 || x == 33 || x == 34 || x >= 36 && x <= 47 || x >= 58 && x <= 64 || x >= 91 && x <= 94 || x == 96 || x >= 123 && x <= 126) {
      if(hashtags) {
        e.preventDefault();
        input_field.html(input_field.html() + "</span>" + String.fromCharCode(x));
        placeCaretAtEnd(this);
        hashtags = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("new")[0].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
     document.getElementsByClassName("new")[0].appendChild(closeSpan());        
      }
    }
    if(x == 13){// return key
      document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');
    }
    
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".delHashtag", function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

```css
#myInputField {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tag span[data-role="remove"] {
  margin-left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tag span[data-role="remove"]:after {
  content: "x";
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myInputField" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Hashtags are created as expected. However, should you click somewhere else in the text and try to create a hashtag, it isn't created where the cursor is. Instead, the hashtag goes to the end of the contenteditable. Not good.

I haven't been able to figure this out. Sure, there are other problems with the code (i.e. no validation of hashtags; first hashtag created after pressing return appears on another line (doesn't remain inside p/div tag)), but I'm focused on this one issue for now.

Could a Javascript ninja give me a hand? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You code also doesn't seem to work properly in Firefox.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You're right. It doesn't work in Firefox or IE. Darn shame really. ☹️