# Highlight words in input field html

Tags: javascript, html, input, highlight

I want some kind of input field in html like textarea, or a div which is editable to highlight special words like Hi or foo. I know that there are some syntax highlighting script out there - Prettify, Syntax Highlighter, highlight.js, etc. However would have to adapt them pretty heavily, because "HI" isn't a token in a programming language. I don't know how to do this / code one by myself.

(I've thought of some kind of string.split by chars and then adding those chars together until I have "HI" for example, but I don't know how to color those words then. span with color? But how would I remove that span if the word is deleted?)

Do you have advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341843/how-to-highlight-a-part-part-of-an-input-text-field-in-html-using-javascript-or

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however using the method you mentioned, I can only highlight one word, not a "Hi" and a "foo". ( I think)

Comment: You can't do that with an input. You would need to use a div (or maybe a span?) and set type="text". On change you would need to parse the div and add highlighting span...

Comment: OK, but how do I listen to onChange in an contenteditable?

Comment: Nevermind, found it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight a part part of an Input text field in HTML using Javascript or JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341843/how-to-highlight-a-part-part-of-an-input-text-field-in-html-using-javascript-or)

Answer (score 2):

Heres a simple example in JSFiddle 
(**Note** updates on blur)

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ug7xmgx0/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="textInput" type="text"contenteditable="true">
 Example on foo bar
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var handleChange = function(e) {
    var newVal = '';
        var words = $('div').text().split(' ');
    $(words).each(function(key, val){
      newVal += `<span class="${val}">${val}</span> `;
    });
    $('div').html(newVal);
  };
  $('div').blur(handleChange);
  handleChange();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.on {
  color: red;
}
.foo {
  color: yellow;
}
```

There are a ton of ways to do this. This is a real simple way to do it, but isn't super efficient or focused on UX.

Comment: Thank you! This works, however it only gets called, when I click out of the div. How would I implement this in an onChange event? I add this onClick function: addEventListener("input", highlight, false); Highlight gets executed whenever the text changes. What should I put inside the function?

Comment: Just got it, but now I faced another problem :( The caret gets put to the start when I update the div and doesn't stay in place... Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You can use `keyup` this will fire after every key stroke. In this example you are replacing the text on `change` which causes the cursor to move to the beginning. You should research how to keep the placement of the cursor on replacement of the text to resolve this new request.

Comment: to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736915/cursor-moves-to-beginning-of-text-when-i-update-text-with-javascript

Comment: I used this: http://jsfiddle.net/WeWy7/3/ and called doSave before your function and doLoad after your function is done. It works now, everything is colored correctly, but I can´t do newlines anymore...