# Contenteditable setCursorPos(elem, pos), pos = getCursorPos(elem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Does anybody have workable solution to get or set cursor position in contenteditable div with elements inside?
What I going to do is to create twitter-like field where I will insert  on @ sign pressed. Problem is that browsers are pretty buggy with contenteditable attribute, so I cant rely on them for insert. So my algorithm is:

- When @ pressed
- GetCursorPos
- get content of div as a string, split it to two halves
- Insert string with span between halves
- Do $(div).html(new_content) - cursor will be dropped to beginning
- move cursor to old_cursor + span's text length

Problem with 2 and 5. I checked following questions:

- [Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)
- [How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)
- [Set the caret position always to end in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230720/set-the-caret-position-always-to-end-in-contenteditable-div)
- [How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity)
- [contenteditable, set caret at the end of the text (cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser)

And many more... There is NO workable solution (FF, Chrome, IE) for setCursorPos(elem, pos) - everywhere is move to the end or save and restore. Also I have getCursorPosition, but sometimes in chrome it gives incorrect results, so this function appreciated also!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked what TinyMCE and others do for this?

Comment: Yes, but there are too much logic for me, I spend already two days for learning all that, this is third day. I have code that works in chrome pretty well, but ONLY in chrome.

Comment: Here is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/vdhm4/ (press @ to insert node + try backspace to remove node)

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16100733/96100?

Comment: I have no chance to check them right now, but at first look they looks pretty well both. Don't know why I didn't pick them up, maybe because I tried too much and there is a mess in my head. Any way I will try them in next 3 days and will post answer here. Thanks, Tim!